# Redis Twitter Clone has a N + 1 Get?

Tags: performance, twitter, clone, redis

I'm looking at the Twitter Clone @ http://redis.io/topics/twitter-clone and noticed a N + 1 -like "get" in the code:

`foreach($posts as $p) {
        if (showPost($p)) $c++;
        if ($c == $count) break;
    }`


`function showPost($id) {
  $r = redisLink();
  $postdata = $r->get("post:$id");
  ...`

I'm aware that all relational database familarity must be left at home when dealing with Redis, but in any case the code above seems pretty suboptimal.

Are there any ways to improve this code, or is my understanding perhaps incorrect?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

That code is suboptimal indeed, but the structure is correct. You will have one key with the post body and one list with each users posts.

Now, to optimize it I see two options.

- using [pipelining](http://redis.io/topics/pipelining) to requests all posts on the same round-trip.
- using [sort](http://redis.io/commands/sort) which allows you more query-like commands.

An example of the second option:

```
redis> LPUSH uid:123:posts 1
(integer) 1
redis> LPUSH uid:123:posts 3
(integer) 2
redis> LPUSH uid:123:posts 5
(integer) 3
redis> LPUSH uid:123:posts 7
(integer) 4
redis> SET post:1 test1
OK
redis> SET post:2 test2
OK
redis> SET post:3 test3
OK
redis> SET post:5 test5
OK
redis> SET post:7 test7
OK
redis> SORT uid:123:posts DESC GET post:* LIMIT 0 100
1) "test7"
2) "test5"
3) "test3"
4) "test1"
```